# Is there a quick, easy way to reverse nested arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

By inverse I mean from the following:

```
$my_array = array(
    "header" => array(
        0 => "Header 1",
        1 => "Header 2"
    ),
    "paragraph" => array(
        0 => "Paragraph 1",
        1 => "Paragraph 2"
    )
);
```

to this:

```
$my_new_array = array(
    0 => array(
        "header" => "Header 1",
        "paragraph" => "Paragraph 1"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "header" => "Header 2",
        "paragraph" => "Paragraph 2"
    )
);
```

I know that I can do this:

```
$my_new_array = array();
foreach ( $my_array["header"] as $key => $header ){
    if ( !is_array( $my_new_array[ $key ] ) ){
        $my_new_array[ $key ] = array();
    }
    $my_new_array[ $key ]["header"] = $header;
}
foreach ( $my_array["paragraph"] as $key => $paragraph ){
    $my_new_array[ $key ]["paragraph"] = $paragraph;
}
```

But I was wondering if there was a quick PHP function to do this or a more optimal way. I couldn't find any such function in the PHP function directory, and i can't think of a more optimal way!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

This would work without using concrete keys:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($my_array as $key => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $idx => $value) {
    $new[$idx][$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_new_array = array();
array_walk($my_array, function($innerArray, $key) use (&$my_new_array) {
  foreach ($innerArray as $index => $val) {
    $my_new_array[$index][$key] = $val;
  }
});
```

...is the best I can come up with, although it's basically the same thing written differently. It does have the advantage of being more dynamic as the key names are not specified explicitly.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LZKDH1)

Answer (score 1):

No built-in function to do this unfortunately, but since the existing answers seem to favor `foreach` I 'm entering this candidate into the race with maximum `array_walk`ness on the agenda:

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array, function($rows, $propKey) use (&$result) {
    array_walk($rows, function($val, $row) use($propKey, &$result) { 
        $result[$row][$propKey] = $val;
    });
});
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/82mOgr).

Comment: In a completely non-critical way, why is `array_walk()` better? I have started to write stuff using it more and more simply because the SO elite seem to favour it, but I've never yet seen a good explanation as to why that is - it seems more untidy/complicated to me...

Comment: @DaveRandom: It's not strictly better. Really, who in their right mind would prefer this version over [Yoshi's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10598855/50079)? It might be faster (haven't measured) and it can allow you to write more "modular" code (which is not applicable to this scenario), but here I would probably judge it as worse.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Although I should say that being able to "think functional" is IMO better for *you*. So even though I can't speak for the SO elite, one possible reason is that training yourself to attack problems this way helps you keep the edge keen.